# Caching Data in Java

Tags: java, caffeine

My implementation is quite simple but it's not doing what's supposed to.
I'm using this cache library: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

When I deploy the app:

`Calls Controller Endpoint -> First time loads data to cache (works fine) -> Wait 10 seconds -> refresh data to cache -> wait 10 seconds -> ... over and over`

The first loading works perfectly. The problem is that after 10 seconds, the reload of the data does not run.

**Controller**

```
   MyData myData = MyData.getInstance();
   Map<String, List<String>> tableOne = myData.cache.get("tableOne");
```

**MyData Class**

```
public LoadingCache<String, Map<String, List<String>>> cache;

public static MyData getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (MyData.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyData();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

 private MyData() {
    this.cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build(key -> MyData.getInstance().loadData(key));
}

private Map<String, List<String>> loadData(String key) {
       // Loads Data. This is only called once and never again!
}
```

Any clue why `refreshAfterWrite` does not run every 10 seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A refresh is triggered on a read after the entry ages past that threshold since its last write.

> Automatic refreshes are performed when the first stale request for an entry occurs. The request triggering refresh will make an asynchronous call to CacheLoader.reload and immediately return the old value.

This can then be combined with expiration so a popular entry is reloaded while an inactive one will expire. In this case a refresh avoids the penalty of callers periodically blocking to reload the entry, as this latency is hidden, while also ensuring it doesn't become too stale.

A periodic reload of the cache is better served by your own thread. For example using `ScheduledExecutorService` could batch reload all of the contents.

Comment: so caffeine cannot be used to get data every x seconds in the background?

Comment: No, it is trivial to do using java.util.concurrent so you don’t need the library for this case.